# MySQL SELECT 2 tables with an INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been working on some MySQL Joins but this one has got me a little confused.
I have 3 tables, `friends`, `posts` and `activity`.

Tables `posts` and `activity` both have a field `userid` which represents the user that the record belongs to. `friends` contains the fields `userid` and `friendid` to represent two users being friends.

If possible, I would like to design a query which will display the records in `posts` AND `activity` from a user which is friends with the logged in user.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT p.*, a.*
    FROM posts AS p, activity AS a
    INNER JOIN friends f ON (p.userid = f.friendid)
    WHERE f.userid = '(Logged In User ID)'
```

However, when I run the above query, I get the following error:

`Unknown column 'p.userid' in 'on clause'`

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Try putting FROM tables within brackets: `FROM ( posts AS p, activity AS a )`.

Comment: Try removing the AS between posts and p. same goes for the as between activity and a. And you don't need brackets around the p.userid = f.friendid + there's no relationship between activity and the other 2 tables so cascadian products is inevitable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need a `UNION`. The following will work if the two tables, `posts` and `activity` have the same number of columns (in same order and similar type). If not, some adjustment is needed in the `SELECT` lists:

```
SELECT p.*
    FROM posts AS p
        INNER JOIN friends f ON p.userid = f.friendid
    WHERE f.userid = '(Logged In User ID)'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.*
    FROM activity AS a
        INNER JOIN friends f ON a.userid = f.friendid
    WHERE f.userid = '(Logged In User ID)'
```

If the two tables have different fields, then you should adjust the 2 select lists, with something like:

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.userid
     , p.post_text     AS text
     , p.post_date     AS date
     , NULL            AS action
    FROM posts AS p
    ...
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id
     , a.userid
     , NULL            AS text 
     , a.activity_date AS date
     , a.action        AS action
    FROM activity AS a
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, is there any way to get this working if the two tables have different fields? `activity` has 5 fields compared to 8 in `posts` and the fields are pretty much completely different apart from the PRIMARY key and userid.

Comment: the short answer is no.  The long answer is maybe.  Sometimes, you can do this using views, where you map the results into a single data set that looks like what you might want to send to a user.  If they are still very different, then you have to do that at the application layer.  SQL Databases are highly structured and do not do arbitrary data well.

Comment: It's also worth noting as I mentioned below that in some versions of MySQL 5.1 and earlier for sure, explicit inner joins are a bad idea.  It's irrelevant on a two way join, but once you add more tables, the degradation that is experienced can be severe.  SQL Server ignores your explicit join order, most other database engines don't.  The query optimizer will believe you are doing this because you know better than it does, which invariably you don't.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! :) I'm going to try adjusting the select lists

Answer (score 1):

two things:

Never use explicit joins in MySQL unless you have to, they may decrease the performance of the query, sometimes very severely.

Your query isn't structured correctly.  You can't use p in an on clause joining a and f, you can only use references from a and f, say:

```
select p.*, a.*
  from posts p, activity a inner join friends f on (a.userid = f.friendid)...
```

most likely what you want is two queries like:

```
select a.* from activity a, friends f, users u
where a.userid = f.friendid
  and u.userid = f.userid;
  and u.userid = 'logged in user'
```

and

```
select p.* from posts p, friends f, users u
where p.userid = f.friendid 
  and u.userid = f.userid
  and u.userid = 'logged in user'
```

if both tables have the same columns, then you can put both in a single query using something like a union:

```
(select a.* from activity a, friends f, users u
    where a.userid = f.friendid
      and u.userid = f.userid
      and u.userid = 'logged in user'
) union (select p.* from posts p, friends f, users u
    where p.userid = f.friendid 
      and u.userid = f.userid
      and u.userid = 'logged in user')
```

if they don't have the same columns, then either you have to make the result of the two selects have the same columns with specific columns and aliases, or go back to two queries.

If you need to sort from this result set, then you'll need a subquery, but be warned, subqueries in MySQL with sorts have been known to be better done in application logic rather than SQL.  Other database engines have a better time with this.

Comment: I guess you meant *"Never use **implicit** joins in MySQL ..."*

Comment: no, I mean explicit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)  If you specify INNER JOIN in this manner instead of using an implicit join as I use, you will be instructing the optimizer to use your order over it's preferred order.  Whether it obeys you or not is another matter.  In SQL Server it ignores you and assumes that it is smarter than you, which it mostly is.  In other engines, it doesn't.  I've done the benchmarks on MySQL 5.0 and 5.1 which show that using implicit joins is better than explicit.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. Explicit joins do not degrade performance. It doesn't improve it either. It improves readability though.

Comment: "Never use explicit joins in MySQL" - I strongly disagree with this. MySQL has a query optimizer, which can be wrong but is usually right. Implicit joins are to be avoided - they can mask flaws in logic, are harder to read and comprehend, and can lead to mistakes (I can't tell you how many implicit joins I've caught in code reviews where not all the "on" conditions were specified and the query was running amok. Better advice is to "Always avoid impact joins - always use explicit joins: they are clearer to write, easier to read, and never hurt your performance".

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here:

1. Whey of are using aliases for tables, you don't need the AS keyword. "from posts p" is sufficient.
2. You don't have any constraints to the activity table, but it's apart of your select statement. This will do a natural join, but will produce a bad Cartesian product and will return that whole table, because you aren't filtering it by the user I'd.

To fix issue 2, you need to add another condition to the where Claus, like:

```
    AND a.userid = p.userid
```

Or add another join clause:

```
   INNER JOIN activity a on a.userid = p.userid
```

Comment: I disagree with advising to avoid the "as" - I find it helps readability enormously and it helps debugging. If you always have "as" any other naked words stand out and can be examined for bugs (I mean that many naked words can be out of place and so are candidates for errors).